# JFormatter won't work - *JFormattedTextField1* Won't format

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

Jformatter won't work, trying to format `JFormattedTextField1` when the form loads (so user can only enter phone numbers in format). But that won't work.

Won't work = Form simply doesn't do anything, `JFormattedTextField1` just stays unmodified

Code:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame(){
        initComponents();
       formattedTextField();
        }


    public void formattedTextField()
   { MaskFormatter formatter;

        formatter = new MaskFormatter("###'-##'-####");
        jFormattedTextField1 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        jFormattedTextField1.setValue("123-45-6789");
}
```

Comment: "That won't work" is *never* enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hej, today i have a guess day and would like to share my solution with you, maybe it fits your needs.

This is a simple class, which initializes a JFrame and adds a JPanel containing a JFormattedTextField and a JButton on it. If you click the Button the Content of the TextField is printed out on the console. If the input does not match an error is displayed on the console.

```
package com.example;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4159266806348540020L;

    private JFormattedTextField tf;
    private JButton clickBtn;


    public MainFrame(final String title) {
        initGUI(title);


    }

    private void initGUI(String title) {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            final MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("###-##-####");
            tf = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            clickBtn = new JButton("Click me!");
            clickBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(!tf.getText().matches(formatter.getMask())) {
                        System.err.println("Your Input does not match the pattern!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(tf.getText());
                    }
                }
            });
            panel.add(clickBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Starting Point

```
package com.example;

public class DemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame("FormattedTextField Demo");
    }
}
```

Please be more detailed in setting up a question next time!

Patrick